Inspecting public key using openssl
A client is attempting to SFTP into our server and is unable to authenticate. I am trying to troubleshoot it. The client has supplied their public key. It reads:
---- BEGIN SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
Comment: "test-key"
...
---- END SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----

I like to inspect the file and tried the following:
openssl rsa -pubin -in pubkey -text -noout # pubkey is filename

This results in:
Could not find private key of public key from pubkey

What am I doing wrong?
PS: This is my openssl version
$ openssl -version
OpenSSL 3.3.2 3 Sep 2024 (Library: OpenSSL 3.3.2 3 Sep 2024)

